# Java: Synchronization between Outer Class and inner class

Tags: java, synchronization

I have code similar to following:

```
class OuterClass
{
   private final AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);

   private class InnerClass extends TimerTask
   {
       public void run()
       {
            ......
            ......
            incremenetCount();
       }
   }

   public void doSomething()
   {
        .......
        .......
        incremenetCount();
   }

   private void incrementCount()
   {
      count.incrementAndGet();
   }
}
```

Is calling `incrementCount` from inner class the same as calling it from any other function in outer class as the synchronization is actually around the variable `count`?

Comment: You may be misunderstanding something about this code. There's no synchronization here.

Comment: Well, I did not put up the decrement part of the code as weel. There are 2 possibilities InnerClass extends TimerTask and it is possible there might be multiple executions of InnerClass exist at the same time. Also what if doSomething was called by an external class at the same instant InnerClass is calling incrementAndCount.

Comment: My point is that you seem to either think that some code here is synchronized or else not know what "synchronization" means in Java. In either case, you should read up on Java concurrency before you try to write any serious multi-threaded code.

Comment: All I said here was I want to make sure the variable count is modified atomically and I gave you scenarios as when atomic modification is essential. Maybe you should try to explain what is you are trying to point out and reserve judgements for later.

Comment: I'm not sure how I can be any clearer. You used the word "synchronization" to describe code which isn't synchronized. I'm just trying to suggest you have a clear understanding of a very difficult subject before diving headlong into it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ***Is calling incrementAndCount from inner class the same as calling it from any other function in outer class [...]***

Yes, calling `incrementCount()` from the inner class is the same as calling `incrementCount()` from the outer count.

All non-static inner classes have an implicit reference to the object of the enclosing class, and it is through this reference the `incrementCount()` will be called.

(Story would have been different if your inner class was *static* though.)

> ***as the synchronization is actually around the variable count?***

Doesn't matter. The same method, is called on the same object, regardless if you do the call from the inner or from the outer class.

Comment: (If the inner class was static, the code would not compile, so "the story" is moot.)

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that it is safe.

To understand why, lets look at this:

```
class SomeClass {
    private final AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);
    ...
    private void incrementCount() {
        count.incrementAndGet();
    }
}
```

There are two questions that need to be considered to determine whether this is thread-safe.

1. Is the fetch of `count` properly synchronized?  Answer yes - because `count` is declared as `final` and there is rule that says that a `final` field can be read without synchronization once the constructor has completed.
2. Is the `incrementAndGet()` method thread-safe?  Answer yes - the specification of the `AtomicInteger` class says so.

Now let us look at the case with the inner class.  The instance of inner class has a hidden final reference to the instance of the outer class.  So ...

```
    public void run() {
        incrementCount();
    }
```

is equivalent to this ...

```
    private final OuterClass $outer;  // initialized by the constructor.
    ...
    public void run() {
        $outer.incrementCount();
    }
```

By the reasoning of point 1. above, the `incrementCount()` call itself is thread-safe.  And the fetch of `$outer` is thread-safe too, because it is implicitly a `final` field.

Comment: That was a thorough explanation. Thanks.